# AWS SNS subscription http endpoint's doPost method not being called

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to call the doPost() method of my servlet by manually creating a topic from AWS console and providing the link of my AWS application which is running on EBS. However, when I call it from a regular html file using a `<form>` the servlet responds successfully. I am providing the snippets of the following files -->

BackEnd.java:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
   <description></description>
   <display-name>BackEnd</display-name>
   <servlet-name>BackEnd</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>BackEnd</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>BackEnd</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/BackEnd</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

PS: The doPost() method just tests whether I am receiving the post request from SNS or not. I understand there are various other steps that I need to include in there.

PPS: Also, I understand that it is a configuration issue. I have done an extensive search to solve that problem but couldn't. I believe many people have asked a similar question, "with similar code snippets" but I think that my problem is fairly different (or so I believe) from the others.

Comment: Is the <url-pattern> the culprit?

Comment: UPDATE1: I am also able to process the doGet() method when I enter the URL in the browser.